# Outlook 2010 Run Script via Rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba, macros

I have the following subroutine in ThisOutlookSession:

```
Sub receiveMtgRequest(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
MsgBox "You have received a meeting request: " & Item.Subject
End Sub
```

I have set it to run whan a message is received that is a meeting invitation or update, but it doesn't run.

I can run it via F5 from the VBE, so I don't understand why it won't run from the rule.

Another odd thing is that it doesn't appear in the Developer => Macros > Macros window.

I suspect it's something to do with the values passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your Outlook Trust Center settings. Open Outlook Options -> Trust Center -> Macro Settings. Make sure you have "Notifications for all macros" or "Enable all macros" is selected.